# Python import problems can only run the app or the code but not both

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I've been searching the site and breaking my head on this. My knowledge seems to limit me to either running code that I can run or code that I can test. Searching for solutions has not yet given me a clearer view on why this is.

I have the following folder structure:

[image]

`__init__` is an empty file. The rest of the files look like:
ClassA.py:

```
class A:
    def hello(self):
        print('hello')
```

ClassB.py:

```
from ClassA import A

class B:
    def hello(self):
        print('hello')
        a = A()
        print(a.hello())
```

main.py:

```
from ClassB import B

if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = B()
    b.hello()
```

test_app.py:

```
import pytest
import sys
import os

sys.path.append(os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__)+'/..'))
from src.ClassB import B

def test_app():
    assert 1 == 1
```

If I run the project from the root of the file all goes well. However if I run the test it tells me:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ClassA'
```

I found the cause of this being `from ClassA import A` in `ClassB.py`. It wants me to add a dot there, making it `from .ClassA import A`. However if I add the dot I can no longer run the code...

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to fix it by placing the tests folder inside the src folder.

However it "feels" wrong to me. I have not yet found a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think by adding `__init__.py` in the **tests** folder your problem will solve.

Comment: That does not fix it. I did make a mistake in my question. I need to add the . to run the tests while the code only runs without the dot.

Comment: if you have an __init__.py file within your src and your test folders, you should be able to add an ```from src.app import *``` statement to your test file and execute the app